# Coffeescript cli keeps giving unexpected end of input for loops

Tags: coffeescript

I've decided to learn coffeescript. Downloaded it today and was playing around with it in the cli but i keep getting odd errors for basic code that works here: https://coffeescript.org/#try:for%20i%20in%20%5B0..5%5D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log%20%22Hello%20%22%20%2B%20i%20

here's an example:

```
>coffee -v
CoffeeScript version 2.3.2

>coffee -c
coffee> for i in [0..5]

[stdin]:1:16: error: unexpected end of input
```

basically

```
for i in [0..5]
```

returns the error:

```
[stdin]:1:16: error: unexpected end of input
```

despite it working perfectly fine on the coffescript website

is something wrong with the cli version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enter the multiline input mode in the CLI to create any codeblocks that need indentation.

Once inside the CLI use `CTRL` + `v`  (if you use a shell / CMD where this is used to paste, try `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `v`

You should see the prompt changes from `coffee>` to `------>`.
Don't forget to use indentation for the inside of your for loop.
Once you've finished your block, hit `ENTER` and use `CTRL` + `v` to execute the multi-line block.

## Example:

writing a loop in normal mode raises an error

```
coffee> for i in [1,2,3]
[stdin]:1:17: error: unexpected end of input
for i in [1,2,3]
            ^
```

First entering multi-line mode (don't forget indentation after the first line)

```
------> for i in [1,2,3]
.......   i * i - i
```

Now hit enter and exit multi-line mode to execute. As with any execution in the CLI, the output of the expression (loop in this case) will be printed:

```
[ 0, 2, 6 ]
```

Comment: Thanks bud, appreciate it!